# Is there literature on the "modified determinant"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, determinant

Here is notation used in the explanation of the question.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and columns $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $A({i_1,\dots,i_s}|{j_1,\dots,j_t})$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing all rows **other than** rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and all columns **other than** $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $\displaystyle A\binom{i_1,\dots,i_s}{j_1,\dots,j_t}$.

Suppose that $i$, $j$ are integers. Define
$$
\rho(i, j)
= \begin{cases}
        0, & i < j;    \\
        1, & i \geq j.
    \end{cases}
$$

Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_n$ are integers. Define
$$
\tau (i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n) = \sum_{1 \leq u < v \leq n} {\rho (i_u, i_v)}.
$$
(If $n = 1$, the sum above is understood to be $0$.)

Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $m \times 1$ matrices. Then $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i, j)$-entry is equal to $[a_j]_{i,1}$. The notation allows us to display a matrix using its columns.

---

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $R$. It is well known that the determinant is equal to (or is defined to be)
$$
\det {(A)}
=
\begin{cases}
    [A]_{1,1},
        & n = 1;    \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}},
        & n \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$

**Fix $\mu \in R$ such that $\mu^2 = 1$.** Define the "modified determinant" of $A$ by
$$
\operatorname{mdt} {(A)}
=
\begin{cases}
    [A]_{1,1},
        & n = 1;    \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {{\color{red}{\mu}}^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \operatorname{mdt} {(A(i|1))}},
        & n \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$

Direct computations prove the following results:

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and that $j$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Then
> $$
> \operatorname{mdt} {(A)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {{\mu}^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \operatorname{mdt} {(A(i|j))}}.
> $$

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_k$ are distinct positive integers less than or equal to $n$, and that $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$. Then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
>     \operatorname{mdt} {(A)}
>     = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
>     {\operatorname{mdt} {\left(
>             A\binom{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k}
>             {j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k}
>             \right)}}
>     {\mu}^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k
>         + j_1 + j_2 + \dots + j_k}
>     \operatorname{mdt} {(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}.
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_n$ are $n$ distinct positive integers less than or equal to $n$. Then
> $$
> \operatorname{mdt} {(A)}
> =
> \sum_{\substack{
> 1 \leq i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n \leq n \\
>         i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n\,\text{are distinct}
>     }}
> {{\mu}^{\tau (i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n)}\,
> {\mu}^{\tau (j_1, j_2, \dots, j_n)}\,
>     [A]_{i_1,j_1} [A]_{i_2,j_2} \dots [A]_{i_n,j_n}}.
> $$

> Suppose that $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Then $\operatorname{mdt} {(I_n)} = 1$.

> Suppose that $j$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Suppose that $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{j+1}$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Suppose that $x$, $y$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Suppose that $s$, $t \in R$. Then
> $$ \begin{aligned}
>             & \operatorname{mdt}
>         {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, \overset{\text{column}\,j}{sx + ty},
>                     a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     \\
>     = {} &
>     s
>     \operatorname{mdt} {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     +
>     t
>     \operatorname{mdt} {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}.
> \end{aligned} $$

> Suppose that $q$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Suppose that $p$ is a positive integer less than $q$. Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Then
> $$ \operatorname{mdt}
> {[a_1, \dots, \overset{\text{column}\,p}{a_q}, \dots,
>     \overset{\text{column}\,q}{a_p}, \dots, a_n]}
> = {\mu}\operatorname{mdt} {[\dots, a_p, \dots, a_q, \dots]}. $$

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Then the "modified determinant" of the transpose of $A$ is equal to that of $A$:
> $$ \operatorname{mdt} {(A^{\mathrm{T}})} = \operatorname{mdt} {(A)}. $$

I notice that $\operatorname{mdt}$ is not alternating (in general), which means that it is not necessarily true that "if $A$ has two equal columns, then $\operatorname{mdt} {(A)} = 0$":
$$
\operatorname{mdt} {
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}
} = 1 + \mu \neq 0\,
\quad\text{unless $\mu = -1$}.
$$

Accordingly, $\operatorname{mdt}$ is not multiplicative (in general), which means that it is not necessarily true that "if $A$, $B$ are square matrices of the same size, then $\operatorname{mdt} {(AB)} = \operatorname{mdt} {(A)} \operatorname{mdt} {(B)}$":
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix},
\\
&
\operatorname{mdt} {\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}
= 1 + \mu,
\\
&
\operatorname{mdt} {\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}
= 0,
\\
& (1 + \mu) \neq (1 + \mu) \cdot 0\,
\quad\text{unless $\mu = -1$}.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Here is my question: **Is there literature on the "modified determinant"?**

I am sorry if the above explanation is poor.

Comment: With $\mu=1$ are we just talking about the permanent? If so has your problem a combinatorial interpretation a la MacMahon?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for pointing out that the permanent, a well studied notion, is the "modified determinant" with $\mu = 1$. It just occurred to me that some properties may preserve even if I replace $-1$ in the definition of the determinant by any other element $\mu$ whose square is unity. I did not know the applications of the permanent to combinatorics.
The "mdt" with $\mu = -1$ is the determinant; the "mdt" with $\mu = 1$ is the permanent. What about the other cases, which are possible in some commutative rings with unity?

Comment: I have been trying to re-write and understand your results in terms of the classical Binet-Cauchy Theorem and its variants. Googling "Binet Cauchy combinatorics" provides many  many many generalisations of determinants some tantalisingly close.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for giving another reference.

Comment: Is this perhaps related to the [immanant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanant)?

Comment: @blargoner I believe so. Thanks for giving another reference.